# Where can I get list of common .NET classes

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using SyntaxHighlighter script by Alex Gorbatchev on my wordpress blog. It's doing pretty well but I want it to highlight common c# classes and not only keywords. So I need list of common c# classes. Any advice where can I get one?

Comment: Do you have them highlighted in Visual Studio as well? Syntax highlighting is usually done to simulate VS code colours to make it easier for developers to read.

Comment: What defines `Common`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about [.NET Framework 3.5 Common Namespaces and Types Poster](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=7b645f3a-6d22-4548-a0d8-c2a27e1917f8&displaylang=en)?

Answer (score 0):

MSDN? Here's the contents of the `System` namespace: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aspx

I don't think there's any consensus on what constitutes "common": you could consider highlighting classes from `System`, `System.Collections.Generic` and `System.Text`. There'll be other important namespaces specific to, say, web development or WPF.

Answer (score 0):

[Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) has always been one of my favorite tools for explorer the .net libs.